# Adding a library to Java CLASSPATH in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java

I am not sure if my question is more related about Ubuntu or Java, so pardon me!

I am trying to compile a java program but I get the following error:

```
package javax.comm does not exist
```

I have downloaded the required package `comm.jar` but I do not know how/where should I install/copy this file.

I read somewhere that this should be in `CLASSPATH`  folder but I dont have this folder.

This is what I get for `java -version` I guess this means I have already installed Java in my system:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.4) (6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

I also have these folders in `/usr/lib/jvm/` :

```
default-java             java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386  java-6-openjdk-i386
java-1.6.0-openjdk       java-6-openjdk           java-7-openjdk-common
java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386  java-6-openjdk-common    java-7-openjdk-i386
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically you specify the classpath when you start your java program with the switch 
`java -cp your.jar xxxx.java`

But you can also permanently add it to your java installation by copying the jar to the default-java/jre/lib/ext folder.

Finally take a look at this question: [Setting multiple jars in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath)

Answer (score 8):

The environment variable CLASSPATH contains a colon-separated list of locations Java should search for classes. Try

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/comm.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it as below:

1. `javac -cp comm.jar XXXXX.java`
   or
2. `export CLASSPATH=comm.jar:$CLASSPATH`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile a class named `foo.bar.Baz`, you must put the `Baz.java` file in a directory  `foo/bar` and launch `javac` from `foo`'s parent directory, ie if you list the content of the current directory you can see `foo` listed. Alternatively, there's the `-sourcepath` command line switch:

```
javac -sourcepath .:/home/asdf/qwerty foo.bar.Baz.java
```

Assuming your class is declared as follows

```java
import foo.bar.*;
public class Baz {}
```

you must put this code in a `/home/raf/foo/bar/Baz.java` file, and changing to the directory `/home/raf` before invoking the compiler.

javac will output the *"package foo.bar doesn't exist"* error if it cannot find a `foo/bar` directory tree in its sourcepath. So you either change to the right directory, or use the `-sourcepath` switch to point to the root of the project, ie the directory containing `javax/comm`. Put your sources in a directory like this:

```
+ /home/raf/project/src
|
+-/javax
  |
  +-/comm
```

and invoke javac from the `src` directory

```
cd /home/raf/project/src
javac $filenames
```

or with the aforementioned switch

```
javac -sourcepath /home/raf/project/src $filenames
```

You need to adjust your `CLASSPATH` to let javac compile against existing archives.